# Help insert flash to my site asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flash

I have a small flash I want to put it in my asp.net site.

Does anyone have an example?

Comment: I  tried  but i wahnt if anyone have very Simple and good

Comment: You realise that ASP.NET is still just plain old regular HTML, HTTP and GETS and POSTS right?  Either way - the two answers that are here provide the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use object tag. Copy the code below in your HTML file where you want the flash to appear:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="movie_name" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="movie_name.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Edit the values such as movie name, height, width, etc. according to your flash element.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net or else, don't leave home without [SWFOBJECT](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)